# Auto Fill second textbox with first textbox input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

auto fill second textbox with the input of first textbox. Like if I choose Jane as first name I want the second textbox to retrieve the last name from database and auto fill it with Doe. I am getting no auto input on second textbox not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the test.php code

```html
<?php   

?>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#firstName").change(function(){
    var firstName=$(this).val();
     if(firstName != ''){
          $.ajax({
                              type:"post",
                              url:"insert_process.php",
                              data:"firstName="+firstName,
         datatype:"json",
                  success:function(data){ $("#lastname").val(data);
           $('#ename').css( "background-color","#B3CBD6"  ) 
        $('#ename').animate({backgroundColor: "#fff",});
          }
                                
                                                        });
     }
     else{
      $("#lastname").val("");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Systems Request </title>

</head>
<body>

<div align="center">

<form action = "insert.php" method ="post" class="form" style="width: 285px; height: 192px">

<br><br>First Name<br>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">

<br>&nbsp;Last Name<br>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" ><br><br>

<input type="submit" value= "Submit Name "><br>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then here is insert_proccess.php code

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db_name= "people";
$pass= "systems399";
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$db_conx=mysql_select_db("people", $con);
$fname=  $_POST["firstName"];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  names WHERE firstName='$fname'   "; 
  $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2 MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $rc = $row["lastname"];

echo json_encode ($rc);
 
?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to solve the problem you are having however as a word of advice I would read up on SQL injection (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your code has serious security issues. Consider what SQL would be executed if I were to type the following into the firstname box: `'; DELETE FROM names; SELECT * FROM names WHERE firstName='`

Comment: I am still new have to figure how to rewrite that to have better security Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the request actually being sent (you can checking the networking tab)? Can you alert the returned data? Basically to be more helpful I would need more information on where exactly the process is failing, at a quick glance, try setting up your data structure more like this:

```
data: { "firstName": firstName }
```

Comment: It's not being inserted yet. It is not getting alert the return data. I type in Jane and nothing happens. It should auto populate the last name Doe in the second textbox when typing Jane on the first name textbox

Comment: @Donny Then the issue is likely either in your script or in your data being sent to your script. can you do `$print_r($_REQUEST);` in your script? the responce will tell us if the data is getting sent

Comment: were would I put that in the script. I am new to this trying to learn as I go.

Comment: @Donny put it in `insert_proccess.php` at the begining, and then have your javascript alert the responce data, let me know what it is

Comment: All I figured it out and got it working thank you for the help. I will try to post code that is  working it was easy.

Comment: I am having another issue though I don't know how to concat two columns.  here is my examlpe $Employee_Name=  $_POST["Employee_Name"];
     $sql="SELECT * FROM  names WHERE FIRSTNAME='$Employee_Name'";  I need it to have FIRSTNAME AND LASTNAME to equal $Employee_Name